# React setState to toggle boolean value not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying something like following:

```
state = {
 claim:{
  isOpen: true
 }
}

handleImagesToggle = () => {
   this.setState(prevState=>({
       ...prevState.claimImages,
       isViewerOpen :!prevState.claimImages.isViewerOpen
   }))
        
  console.log(this.state.claimImages) // always logs true   
}

render(){
  return(
   <Button onClick={() => this.handleImagesToggle()} >Toggle</Button>
 )
}
```

Here I'm expecting to toggle `claimImages` value in every click. But current code is not working. What's wrong here ?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-surf-88e15?file=/src/Component.js

Comment: Spreading a boolean or trying to access a property on undefined should crash your application, and the state shape you posted looks nothing like the update you are trying to make. Please post a one to one example of your code

Comment: @AsafAviv please check the sandbox added above

Comment: this whole example doesn’t seem right.. too many mistakes to start explaining, you should go to react class components basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to toggle a nonexistent property, instead toggle the `isOpen` property inside `state.claim`

```js
handleImagesToggle = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    claim: {
      ...prevState.claim,
      isOpen: !prevState.claim.isOpen
    }
  }));
```